# Find filenames with number in name lower than 1950

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, busybox

I have the following problem: I have a list of files like this

```
File256name.txt
File307list.cvs
File2014text.xls
```

I would use the command "find" to only find files with number in the name lower than 1950 so as the previous list I would only have these files listed

```
File256name.txt
File307list.cvs
```

I tried this command

```
find . -type f  \( -iname '*[1-9][0-9][0-9]*' \)
```

but it will display also files containing number in the name >1950

As additional indication all files can have different filenames and extensions and the position of the number is unpredictable...I'm looking for a simple command to use with find (for me is mandatory to use find) by including a formula to select only files that contains numbers lower than 1950

Also consider the limitation of my linux version that is BusyBox v1.16.1

Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, awk is available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a regex that will differenciate the decade in respect to century:

```
.*(19[5-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]{3}).*
```

(This will find 4-digit numbers greater than or equal 1950).

Using this regex you may use the negate option of `find` to get files with no number >= 1950. To eliminate files without any number, use a second criteria.

I've not tested this with find, but the regex you use allows for 1000 < 1950.

Edit:

The full command:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*[0-9].*' \! -regex '.*(19[5-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]{3}).*'
```

With busybox's find some more escaping is necessary:

```
find . -regex '.*[0-9].*' \! -regex '.*\(19[5-9][0-9]\|[2-9][0-9]\{3\}\).*'
```

Comment: OP's example includes files with only 3 numbers

Comment: @Jidder: Which will work, too. The regex matches numbers >= 1950 (which are 4-digit at least) and then negates the result. This way the regex does not match 3-digit-numbers and because of the negation the find criteria will match (which is right for all numbers < 1000).

Comment: find: unrecognized: -regextype    

I cannot use it

Comment: Now tested with busybox 1.21.1

Comment: ...and if I want to specify only some extensions?

Comment: ...add `\.txt` at the end of the first regex?

Comment: Yes it's perfect, could I also specify in this way more extensions like \.txt\.cvs\.xls? Sorry but I don't really have any idea about that.

Comment: Just found it...something like .\(jpg\|png\) correct?

Comment: @Maxrock70: almost correct. Use escaping just as in the second regex of my example

Answer (score 3):

Pipe into (G)awk

```
find . -type f | awk 'match($0,/[0-9]+/,a)&&a[0]<1950'
```

This only matches files with numbers in, and then checks if the number is below 1950 and prints.
it will work for file with only 1 digit or with 4 and also with leading zeros.

Comment: I tried your command but I still get the both files

MyNas> find /volume1/homes/admin/tmp/ -type f  | awk 'match($0,/[0-9]+/,a)&&a[0]
<1950'
/volume1/homes/admin/tmp/ciccio2014ooo.txt
/volume1/homes/admin/tmp/ciccio306oooo.cvs

Comment: Are those the results or have you passed those files to awk ?

Comment: Check the version of Awk, match is only avialable in GAWK, i probably should have mentioned that, sorry :(

Comment: no, I mean by running your command exactly as you posted the result is the list of the two files

Comment: these are the option available:

`-v VAR-VAL`
`-F SEP`
`-f FILE`

Comment: this busybox distribution is very limited :-(

Answer (score 0):

It can be done simply in bash with **character classes** and **substring removal**:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "$@"; do
    ffn="${i##*/}"
    num="${ffn//[^0-9]/}"
    [ "$num" -le 1950 ] && echo "$i => $num"
done
```

**input:**

```
File1949text.doc
File1950text.doc
File1951text.dat
File2014text.xls
File256name.txt
File307list.cvs
```

**output:**

```
$ bash ../fn1950.sh File*
File1949text.doc => 1949
File1950text.doc => 1950
File256name.txt => 256
File307list.cvs => 307
```

Comment: The OP uses BusyBox. Not bash.

Comment: Ooh, sorry I overlooked the busybox requirement. I looked for something with `find`, but could not find anything that was **different/more efficient** than the `regex` approach taken by urzeit, but didn't find any. Sorry for the mix-up.